# JAXB parse of Atom.xsd produces validation errors

Tags: xsd, jaxb, atom-feed

I am seeking to use JAXB to parse the Atom feed coming back from invoking Sharepoint 2010's REST service, and having the JAXB bind and compile happen on build in eclipse.  I downloaded a couple different versions of the atom xsd I found online (they differ only in some header attributes), including this one (http://www.kbcafe.com/rss/atom.xsd.xml) but am CONSISTENTLY getting the following errors regardless of which I use:

```
     [xjc] [WARNING] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
     [xjc]   line 14 of file:/C:/rest_workspace/eDocs/src/gov/afms/edocs/rest/jaxb/schemas/AtomSchema2.xsd
     [xjc] [ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xml:base' to a(n) 'attribute declaration' component.
     [xjc]   line 292 of file:/C:/rest_workspace/eDocs/src/gov/afms/edocs/rest/jaxb/schemas/AtomSchema2.xsd
     [xjc] [ERROR] s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'commonAttributes' must match (annotation?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)). A problem was found starting at: attribute.
     [xjc]   line 292 of file:/C:/rest_workspace/eDocs/src/gov/afms/edocs/rest/jaxb/schemas/AtomSchema2.xsd
```

I have seen some comments saying taht Java5 Xerces had some issues, but I echo out my java version from my ant script and am using 1.6.  The node at line 14 is:

```
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd" />
```

The node at line 292 is:

```
        <xs:attribute ref="xml:base" />
```

Note that eclipse is also flagging these things as errors.  For the warning, eclipse says "XSD: The location 'http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd' has not been resolved", for the error line it says "XSD: Attribute reference 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace#base' is unresolved".  It also errors on 293 which is similar to the above but pointing at lang instead of base.

It's wierd to me that the parser is trying to resolve the reference to the namespace document since that appears to be just an HTML doc explaining namespaces, NOT an XSD or DTD.  But this Atomschema2.xsd isn't something I made up, it was downloaded.

What am I supposed to be doing here?  Is there a better atom schema?  Should I modify the schema I downloaded to chage the references?  Some third thing?

Comment: You may find the following post useful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Answer (score 2):

The error is typically caused by the DTD DOCTYPE on top of the xml.xsd file; I never tried to figure it out with JAXB, but I can guarantee that if you download, fix the references, and remove the <!DOCTYPE...[]> from the xml.xsd file, JAXB will work out of the box with the schema you pointed at (I just tried it in NetBeans 7.1 with no issues). I guess a good question now is how to get JAXB's xjc to ignore the DTD...

UPDATE: -catalog in the command line might do it, please read [this](http://www.mirthproject.org/svn/tags/0.5/resources/jaxb/samples/catalog-resolver/readme.txt).